# Bloodhound: Twitter Typeahead is not showing all results fetched from remote/ajax

Tags: javascript, tokenize, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

I am using Twitter Typeahead in a really simple setup.  It makes a remote call to a server to get a list of names and identifiers as a json array, such as the following:

```
[{"value":"Declan Strosin","data":"b2c9d118-2e7a-4516-bc50-5505cbfcc834"},{"value":"Jany Legros","data":"d8b53d8c-d952-4fed-bc22-5932094abca1"}]
```

The problem is that sometimes the the Typeahead will render all the matching options, but other times it will show only a few.  There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to what it decides to render.

For example, I might type "and", and receive from the server a list of 10 users with names like "Sandy Blogs", "Andrew Blogs", "John Sanderson", etc, and it will list all 10 users.  The correct 3 letters are highlighted too.

For other searches however, "ros", "dan", etc, it might pull back 10 users but only render two or three.

I suspect the problem is with my Bloodhound datum tokenizer, but don't really know what to do about it.  Here's my Bloodhound setup.

```
    return new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: url + '?term=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
    });
```

I have read this article, https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/migration/0.10.0.md#tokenization-methods-must-be-provided, but am still none the wiser.

Edit: I have now experienced cases where 10 or more entries are pulled back from the server, but nothing is rendered by the Typeahead.

Comment: Are you sure your ajax request is working perfectly? Share more code, the code you posted above working perfectly for me.

Comment: It would be useful if you provide the code where you are initializing the typeahead.

Comment: A Json example would be helpful, what is displaying, and what is not

Comment: Are you sure when you write `and`, John Sanderson was displayed? I believe your Bloodhound will only match if your query matches the start of each word.

Comment: Bloodhound matches everything sent over remote, even if the query is not present int the result anyway.

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be a problem with your code. You can try the following:

- Use a **more recent/maintained version**:  The original Typeahead has **NOT** received any updates since 3+ years now(checkout [github](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/commits/master)). But there's an actively maintained [fork](https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js). (as of 2018)
- use **Identify()**: It seems that you have not set the `identify()` option while setting up Bloodhound. According to the [official documentation](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#options), it is recommended to use it so that your datums are always unique.
- Lastly, **cross-check**: with the Tutorial in the reference to ensure that you haven't missed out anything.

*Reference:*
**[Typeahead Tutorial @Digital Fortress](http://digitalfortress.tech/tutorial/smart-search-using-twitter-typeahead-bloodhound/)**

Answer (score 2):

Your code is exactly fine, there is no problem with with. Bloodhound has an issue with the limit setting of the bloodhound suggestions. You can see issue details [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1201).

At present I cannot say what is causing the issue, as trying different combinations of result list, it does not make any sense to me.

But for now the quick solution is to set the **limit to 20**, and it works just fine. Hope the developers solve this issue soon. Till then this is your best bet.

```
return new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 20,
    remote: {
        url: url + '?term=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
});
```

Comment: @kimPrince some more info is required, typeahead version, initialization code, ajax url etc